# Android: How Reliable is InputStream.read() and its "-1" return?

Tags: java, android

My question is related to a method **InputStream.read()** - socket programming.

Every source i have found states that when the server or client closes the connection, "-1" is returned.

But, "what if", just saying, "what if" the connection *is* closed but **read()** does not return "-1"? We rely on someone else's code. The reason i am worried is because in order to read the remote end's input, one will have to create an infinite loop and I have always been thought to stay away from infinite loops. With Java however, it looks like I do not have a choice! Here is a sample:

```
int b = 0;
    while (true)
    {
      b = inputStream.read()
      if (b == -1) break; // connection closed
    }
```

or

```
 while (b > -1)
 b = inputStream.read()
```

What *if* something happens, and -1 never becomes true? One will end up in an infinite loop increasing the temperature of someone's device and wasting CPU cycles! How can one be certain?

References: [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29][1] and [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29][2]

I want to have a fail-safe check. What I have done in the loop is also do a check whether socket has become null and if so, break the loop.

```
 while (b > -1)
    {
      b = inputStream.read()

      if (socket == null) break;
      if (outputStream == null) break;
    }
```

What else can I do to ensure the loop exists in case "-1" never becomes true?

Comment: *"We rely on someone else's code."* Any time you're programming for any system you haven't written the BIOS for, you're relying on someone else's code. (Heck, even if you wrote the BIOS, there's still the CPU's microcode.)

Comment: When u talk about Socket Programming. There will be socket time out. Which could be used to stop this infinite loops.

Comment: You could rely on `IOException` at least.

Comment: If -1 never becomes true, it's your JRE's problem, not yours.

Comment: Thank you all that replied. Some time ago, when I first started programming Android (last December) I was experimenting with sockets. It must have been my code as I was learning the fundamentals of Android and "multi-threading" at the time. I somehow ended up in an infinite loop while I was doing what I showed above but I have been unable to reproduce the error ever since and <s>I don't clearly remember</s> just remembered what the error was. Log.e() kept spamming me with -1 -1 -1 -1 as I was printing the return values with Log.e() and I had a while (true) which is when I decided to replace it

Answer (score 2):

> One will end up in an infinite loop increasing the temperature of
>   someone's device and wasting CPU cycles!

This is not true and I think a major part of why you ask this question. `read()` does **not** busy wait (i.e ask for the CPU constantly) if it doesn't have anything to read. So in practice there wouldn't be a major problem if -1 isn't returned.

`read()` also throws an `IOException` in case something goes wrong with the reading (for example if the `InputStream` is closed). Making sure you have have the loop inside the try-block together with checking for -1 is more than enough for making sure it'll get out of the loop, as such:

```
try {
    int b;
    while ((b=inputStream.read() > -1)
    {
       //Do something
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Very good, but read() won't throw an exception on trying to read past EOF.

Answer (score 0):

> what if", just saying, "what if" the connection is closed but read() does not return "-1

There is no such condition. It is a contradiction in terms.

> What if something happens, and -1 never becomes true?

It can't.

> One will end up in an infinite loop increasing the temperature of someone's device and wasting CPU cycles!

Untrue. If this impossible situation ever happened the read() would block indefinitely without consuming any CPU at all.

> How can one be certain?

You could believe the specification, and not ask self-contradictory questions.

NB Testing for the socket or the input stream being null *after* you've attempted a read and haven't had an exception or an EOS is futile.

Comment: "NB Testing for the socket or the input stream being null after you've attempted a read and haven't had an exception or an EOS is futile" - that is so true, the code is illogical. If socket becomes null right after read() returns, the next time the loop runs, it will throw an exceptrion

Comment: @nwx 'Becomes null' *how?* That's the real question. Variables don't just 'become null' spontaneously.